# obtener return de un dialogo shellscript?

Tags: shell, macos

Estoy intentando crear un script `.sh` para capturar la acción de un dialogo en Mac que muestra los botones `No` y `Si`, para después ejecutar código dependiendo de la respuesta, no he logrado hacer que tome las acciones del usuario.

Esto es lo que he logrado:

```
    #!/bin/sh
    #!/usr/bin/env bash

    # error "Message"
    function advertencia() {
    osascript <<EOT
    tell app "System Events"
    display dialog "$1" buttons {"No","Si"} default button 2 with icon caution with title "$(basename $0)"
    return result
    end tell
    EOT
    }

    resultado=$(advertencia "Selecciona una opcion:")

    if ["$resultado" == "Si"]; then
       advertencia "Seleccionaste Si"
    else
       advertencia "Seleccionaste no"
    fi
```

Pero no funciona.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontre esta manera de hacerlo y me funcionó:

```
#!/bin/sh

osascript <<EOT
app "System Events"
set answer to the button returned of (display dialog "Selecciona una opcion" buttons {"Si", "No"} default button 2)
if answer = "No" then
display dialog "Seleccionaste No" buttons {"Aceptar"}
else
if (answer = "Si")then
display dialog "Seleccionaste Si" buttons {"Aceptar"}
end if
end if
return  -- Suppress result
end
EOT
```